# Show the location of any opened file

Tags: windows-xp, file-location

How do I find out the location of any opened files or applications in Windows XP 32 bit?

For example, I have an application running as well as some Excel files open. How do I quickly find out their locations?

Comment: Do you want to know the location of the applications itself? Or the location of the documents which are open in your applications?

Comment: for example Skype and one excel file is opened . i want to know location of Skype exe and excel file.

Comment: Those are 2 separate questions, see my answer.

Comment: What a senseless question.

Comment: What is the purpose of this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can also list all File-Handles.

Comment: no it doesnt show thelocation of files. it only shows the location of exe

Comment: @Jitendra vyas: That's odd, mine does...check `View -> Show Lower Pane` and `View -> Lower Pane View -> Handles`.

Comment: Aggreed, but that list can be very long. It's not always easy to spot the one which is the actual document being edited/viewed.

Answer (score 2):

Those are actually 2 separate questions:

- To know the location of the application itself (the .exe file), like [@bobby](https://superuser.com/questions/124318/how-to-know-location-of-any-opened-file/124320#124320) also mentions: a tool like Process Explorer shows the locations of the exe's of each separate process that is running.
- To know the location of the file that's open inside an application, the easiest way is to do `File - Save As...` in the specific application. This will show you immediately where that specific file is that you are editing/viewing.

Comment: ok so there is no other way then "Save as"

Comment: @Jitendra: Well, there kind of is (see my comment to Bobby on his answer), but the "Save As" method is easier IMO.